# React Native - use bottom sheet to navigate to screens in BottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I want to make last Tab as Show More tab and when i clicked on it, bottom sheet open which has remaining tab. I can make bottom sheet, and it is working but how can i go to the screen on bottom sheet after clicking on it like by clicking on setting it take me to setting Screen.

Below is example that i need to achieve

[image]